Mac M1 - GLFW Working using brew install but not downloaded binaries
Using Installed Package - Works
first I install GLFW via arch -arm64 brew install glfw.
then linked to my project using the CMakeList.txt:
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        glfw
        "-framework OpenGL"
        "-framework Cocoa"
        "-framework IOKit"
        "-framework CoreVideo"
)

The additional frameworks are necessarry as per the GLFW docs. This method works!
Using Downloaded Binaries - Does Not work
Download the MacOs binaries from GLFW Downloads
then linked to my project using the CMakeList.txt:
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/binaries/GLFW/lib-arm64/libglfw3.a
        "-framework OpenGL"
        "-framework Cocoa"
        "-framework IOKit"
        "-framework CoreVideo"
)

Using this method I get a long string of errors:
: && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/surf.dir/src/main.cpp.o -o surf  /Users/me/CLionProjects/surf/lib/binaries/GLFW/lib-arm64/libglfw3.a  -framework OpenGL  -framework Cocoa  -framework IOKit  -framework CoreVideo && :
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_objc_msgSend$IBeamCursor", referenced from:
      __glfwCreateStandardCursorCocoa in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)

...

  "_objc_msgSend$zoom:", referenced from:
      __glfwCreateWindowCocoa in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwRestoreWindowCocoa in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwMaximizeWindowCocoa in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I suppose the next thing to do is to try and build from source taking advantage of the glfw3.pc file. However, seeing that it works from brew, I would expect to have the necessary dependencies?..

This answer might be relevant, but I've never seen that error before otherwise. I downloaded a copy of glfw3 and the dylib also links to libobjc

Add -framework AppKit? IBeamCursor is listed as a property of the AppKit NSCursor class

I got things working from a local binary by using the libglfw.3.4.dylib downloaded form brew and using frameworks: OpenGL, Cocoa, IOKit, CoreVideo and CoreFoundation.
